# Physics of tagging at B factories

Tags: particle-physics, statistical-mechanics, experimental-physics

At some B factories, mesons carrying $b/\bar{b}$ quarks are created by $e^-e^+$ collisions at $\gamma(4S)$ resonance. $\gamma(4S)$ decays into antisymmetric wavefunction given by 
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left|B_0(\vec{k})\right>\left|\bar{B}_0(-\vec{k})\right>-\left|\bar{B}_0(\vec{k})\right>\left|B_0(-\vec{k})\right>) $$
Following this, I have two questions:

1. This wavefunction clearly violates Bose statistics. So the full wavefunction has to be symmetric. What is the other part of this wavefunction? (spin is zero)
2. The fact that it is an antisymmetric wavefunction helps in tagging flavours of particles. I didn't understand this statement. Please explain how. Also, what if its a symmetric wavefunction(like in case of $\gamma(5S)$). Can't we tag flavours there?

Comment: What's the pb in being symmetric? $B_0$ and $\bar{B}_0$ are not the same particle. So why invoking spin-statistic theorem?

Comment: @Paganini  Even I don't understand the problem with symmetric wavefunctions. I am not invoking spin-statistics. I mentioned that spin is zero so that nobody else invokes it. I am trying to understand the role of antisymmetric states in tagging.

Comment: so I don't understand the first point of your question. Why do say that "the full wave function has to be symmetric"?

Comment: @Paganini Because according to Bose statistics, full wavefunction should be symmetric under exchange of two similar mesons.  I may not be able to make it clear. You can check CP violation by Branco for this (Article # $8. 7 $and $29.3.2$)

Comment: that's precisely the point! your 2 mesons are not identical. one is the antiparticle of the other. If however you want to consider them as 2 states of the same particle, you have to consider  the way the global wave function change by charge conjugation symmetry.

Comment: @Paganini I lost you here. What I am thinking is if you interchange both $B_0$ and $\bar{B}_0$, you will get a minus sign. This is what violating Bose statistics. Did you check the reference?

Answer (score 3):

This is only an answer to the first question. When you invoke the spin statistic theorem (i.e. the fact that identical particles, here bosons must have a symmetric wave function) for the system made of $B^0$ and $\bar{B}^0$ mesons, you have to consider:

1. spin exchange
2. position exchange
3. Charge conjugation

in order to build the whole wave function.

1) has no incidence here since $B^0$ has a spin 0.

2) Doing $\vec{k} \leftrightarrow -\vec{k}$ introduces a minus sign. In other words your system has an odd parity.

3) has also to be considered since $B^0$ and $\bar{B}^0$ are not strictly speaking the same particles, one being the antiparticle of the other. Changing in your wave function the $B^0$ by $\bar{B}^0$ but keeping the original $\vec{k}$ (or $-\vec{k}$) introduces another minus sign.

So, globally the changes $\vec{k} \leftrightarrow -\vec{k}$ followed by $B^0 \leftrightarrow \bar{B}^0$ don't change the sign of the wave function as it should for this system.

Remark: point 2 and 3 can be checked by looking at the quantum numbers of the $\Upsilon(4s)$ which has $J^{PC}=1^{--}$ meaning an odd parity and an odd C-parity.